# Error when trying to set up Tab Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm currently receiving the error 'Got an invalid value for 'component' prop for the screen 'Home'. It must be a valid React Component.'' I'm trying to link the tab navigator to a series of different screens.
Please see the code below and thanks in advance. I'm a beginner clearly lol

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { create } from 'react-test-renderer';
import Home from './Screen/Home'
import Future from './Screen/Future'

const Tabs=createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function App (){
return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tabs.Navigator>
 <Tabs.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
 <Tabs.Screen name='Future' component={Future} />

  </Tabs.Navigator>


</NavigationContainer>


);
}
const Home= ()=>{
return(
<View>
<Text>HOME NAV</Text>
</View>
)
}
const Future= ()=>{
  return(
  <View>
  <Text>Future</Text>
  </View>
  )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function name is HomeScreen but you are using Home as a component in your tab navigation. Please check it and let me know if it wokrs

Comment: This should be rather a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back,  I don't want to use those, I want to use the screens imported above. Please see correct code which gives the same error

Comment: I've edited the code and now the error read ' Home has already been declared'?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
const HomeScreen= ()=>{...}
```

to

```
const Home= ()=>{...}
```

Comment: Hi Shan, when I do that I get the error; ' Home has already been declared' Thoughts?

Comment: because you are importing HOME and down below you are declaring again in the same screen. That's why you are getting that error

Comment: create your Home component in another file and then import it in navigation. Or remove the line `import Home from './Screen/Home` and do all your code of Home component in navigation(second one is  a bad idea btw).